# Trouble with profile details

Tags: user-interface, facebook

I what to develop a FBML internal application. I used:

```
require 'facebook.php';$appId ='xxx';$secret ='xyx';$facebook = new Facebook(array( 'appId'  => $appId,  'secret' => $secret,  'cookie' => true,)); $session = $facebook->getSession();
```

But I can not get the profile data of the user logged in..uid,name, etc...

Where I get it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to respond to the user login attempt and also retrieve the cookie...

```
//attach this below your current code
  FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    window.location.reload();
  });
```

And then also

```
//somewhere before you load the page...
$cookie = get_facebook_cookie(FACEBOOK_APP_ID, FACEBOOK_SECRET);
```

Check http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ and look at Single Sign On with Javascript SDK

Comment: Was this helpful or is more assistance required?  Thanks.